# addFieldError not working in Struts2

Tags: struts2

i am learning struts2 and facing some problems with showing the addFieldError   message..nothing shows up ..
when i run my project and leave userID field blank it does enters into the validate method and even satisfies the condition of **isEmpty** method but it doesnt shows up any error message..
i put a s.o.p. statment in the **isEmpty** method to see ,it is entering or not..
the statment gets printed on console , the url changes to **../MyStruts/validation.action** with no errors anywhere and nothing happens further..

can someone tell me where i am doing it wrong..
here is my code..

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

 <struts>


 <package name="validate" extends="struts-default">
 <action name="validation"  class="com.staction.DataAction">
 <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
 <result name="input">/form1.jsp</result>
 <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
  </action>  </package>

   </struts>
```

form1.jsp

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

  <html>
 <head>

</head>
<s:form action="validation">
<h1>
<s:textfield label="UserName" name="userID" />
<s:password label="password" name="password" />
</h1>
<s:submit />
</s:form>
<s:a href="forget">forget password </s:a>
    </html>
```

Action class...

```
    package com.staction;

     import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

     import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport; 
     import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

    public class DataAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
User user;
DataCheck dc;
public DataAction() {
    user=new User();
    dc=new DataCheck();
}

@Override
public void validate() {
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getUserID()))
    {
        System.out.println("hellp");
        addFieldError("user.userID", "wtf!!!!");
    }

}
public String execute()
{
    System.out.println("user.userID");
    /*      if(dc.isValid(user))
{
    return SUCCESS;
}*/
    return ERROR;
}

@Override
public User getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return user;
}
```

}

and finally the `User` class..

```
package com.staction;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class User{
String userID;
String password;

public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}
public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
   }
```

Comment: got some clue here ..  if i remove the modeldriven interface implementation and put the userID and password field in myDataAction class then it works fine..   can someone tell me why so ?   .. please someone try this thing out and reply

Answer (score 2):

Your form:

```
<s:textfield label="UserName" name="userID" />
```

Your field error:

```
addFieldError("user.userID", "wtf!!!!");
```

See the difference?

Also:

- I hope your code isn't actually formatted randomly like that; it's very difficult to read.
- Why does your `User` class extend `ActionSupport`? If it's not an action, don't extend the base default action: it's pointless, and misleading.
- Consider naming actions something meaningful: *most* actions are "data actions".
- When posting examples, kindly trim out commented-out code and stuff that isn't directly related to the specific question.

Comment: but i think interceptor makes userID available to all jsp's but not to Action Classes..and sorry for bad formatting .. actually i tried the valdate method in user class thats why it is there ..i forgot to remove it while posting here...sorry for that

Comment: for code formatting, CTRL+SHIT+F in Eclipse after having selected the text may help :)

Comment: Your question has already been answered :/ change addFieldError to match your property name (I don't use ModelDriven but it should work)

Comment: i changed it but it didnt work.. can you tell me then what you use if you are not using modeldriven...??

Answer (score 0):

In addition to response of Dave Newton, you must delete "user." in addFieldError so that Struts2 takes automatically the right object using getModel, or you must add set/get methods for object user in Action so that object is accessed using getter.

Answer (score -1):

Jst use the name of your field that to be validated... Change ur code to

```
addFieldError("UserName", "wtf!!!!");
```

Comment: Which is what I said six months ago, no?